# sql or trick to search through whole database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

is there a way to actually query the database in a such a way to  search for a particular value in every table across the whole database ?

Something like a file search in Eclipse, it searches accross the whole worspace and project ?

Sorry about that .. its MS SQL 2005

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: You should mention the RDBM you're using, this requires some RDBM-specific code and procedures

Comment: SQL is vague, its just a language definition. The actual method will depend on the actual database engine used. MySQL? SQLite? MSSQL? mSQL? other?

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Workbench/J](http://www.sql-workbench.net) has a built in [tool](http://www.sql-workbench.net/SearchTables_png.html) and [command](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/wb-commands.html#command-search-data) to do that.

It's JDBC based and should also work with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the LIKE operator, and search through each field separately. i.e.

```
    SELECT * FROM <table name> 
    WHERE (<field name1> LIKE '%<search value>%') OR
           (<field name2> LIKE '%<search value>%') OR
```

... etc.

This isn't a quick way though.

I think the best way would be to 
1) programatically generate the query and run it
2) use a GUI tool for the SQL server you are using which provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use union operator like

> (SELECT * from table A where `name` = 'abc') UNION (SELECT * from
>   table B where `middlename` = 'pqr')

and so on
use full text search for efficency
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, your best bet is to write a procedure to do this. But to give you some pointers you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables` to get a list of all the tables in a given database and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` to get a list of all columns. These tables also give you the datatype of columns. So you will need a few loops on these tables to do the magic.

It should be mentioned most RDBMSs nowadays support these schemas.

Answer (score 0):

In phpmyadmin, go to your database, reach the search tab.

Here you will be able to select all of your tables and search through your entire db in one time.

Comment: phpmyadmin is for MySQL not for sql server.